Will CTE work with an INSERT in databricks / spark sql?
I don't have a databricks environment yet to run the queries and test stuff.
Could someone please help check if the below is a valid query :
insert into pqr.public.abc
with city_mapping as
(
 select date,store_id,code,city from pqr.public.def where date>= current_date-1
 group by 1,2,3,4
)
, runrate as(
select a.date,
  case when city is null then 'Null' else city end as city,
  a.store_id,b.code,round(sum(runrate),4) total_rr from pqr.public.lmn a
left join city_mapping b
on a.store_id=b.store_id and a.date=b.date
where a.date>=current_date-1
group by 1,2,3,4)
select city,store_id,total_rr from runrate


https://community.cloud.databricks.com/ provides a free databricks environment. Why not test your query there yourself?

This is not a valid query. The insert command should be before the actual select, not before the "with" clause. Also the definition of "runrate" does not close .

Updated query above - it was a sample one and added an answer also.. it actually works

It actually worked. Please see the screenshots below:
1.created a managed table and added 2 rows


Created a 2nd table and wrote the query to get data from table 1 created in previous step using WITH clause



SELECT query ran on 2nd table



Here is a minimal reproducible example that uses the same syntax as TSQL:
create table catalog.schema.table(
  col1 int, col2 int, col3 string
);

with source as (
  select 1 as col1, 2 as col2, 'a' as col3
)
insert into catalog.schema.table select * from source;


select * from catalog.schema.table;




col1
col2
col3




1
2
a



